# Get all MySQL changes done after a certain time

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a system where there's a mysql database to which changes are done. Then I have other machines that connect to this mysql database every ten minutes or so, and re-download tables concerning them (for example, one machine might download tables A, B, C, while another machine might download table A, D, E).

Without using Debezium or Kafka, is there a way to get all MySQL changes done after a certain timestamp, so that ***only those changes*** are sent to a machine requesting the updates, instead of the whole tables ? ... For example, machine X might want all mysql changes done since it last contacted the mysql database, and then apply those changes to its own old data to update it.

Is there some way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can be setup to automatically replicate databases, tables etc. automatically. If the connection is lost, it will catch up when the connection is restored.

Take a look at this page [MySQL V5.5 Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html), or this one [MySQL V8.0 Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Debezium as a [library embedded](http://debezium.io/docs/embedded/) into your application, if you don't want or can deploy a Kafka cluster.

Alternatively, you could directly use the [MySQL Binlog Connector](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java) (it's used by the Debezium connector underneath, too), it lets you read the binlog from given offset positions. But then you'd have to deal with many things yourself, which are handled by solutions such as Debezium already, e.g. the correct handling of schema metadata and changes (e.g. additions of columns to existing tables). Usually this involves parsing the MySQL DDL, which by itself is quite complex.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead of Debezium

Comment: To the person who downvoted this answer, can you share the reason for it? Thanks!